# .htaccess custom redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i want to be able to have any links on my site like this

mail/asdassda2131dfdsfdsds

actually show this :

/index.php?option=com_loans&view=mail&guid=asdassda2131dfdsfdsds

using htaccess

without actually seeing the latter url (ie mail/asdassda2131dfdsfdsds remains in the address bar)

anyone ?

tnx
SC

Answer (score 0):

Add below rewrite rule to the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^mail/ (.*)$ index.php?option=com_loans&view=mail&guid=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks! bur that actually redirects me to  index.php?option=com_loans&view=mail&guid=$1 - is there any way to keep mail/asdassda2131dfdsfdsds in the url box ?

Comment: The "L" flag added in the end makes sure you url doesnt change!

Comment: Are there any other redirects that redirect your index.php to another subdomain??

Comment: no - this is my full file  : 
RewriteRule ^mail/(.*)$ index.php?option=com_loans&view=mail&guid=$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

##
##RewriteRule apply/affiliate/leadcheck /index.php?option=com_loans&task=dedupe&format=raw [NC,P]
##RewriteRule apply /index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102 [R=301,L,QSA]
  
 
 
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /